# Front end w/o Back end?

Tags: frontend, web-frontend

1. I'll post my question.
2. Reason for asking.
3. My results when i look for the answer.

1.1. Q: Can I launch a website I've built in HTML, CSS, JavaScript without knowing any back end languages. (or do i absolutely have to have back end such as python?).

2.2. Reason for asking, I am building a site for a friend's brand GKnowByrd, though i don't know yet if i can launch it without a back end.

3.3. Every time I search for this, I end up with "Learn so an so here" type links. It's like no one on the internet can be straight forward. (or i ask in a round-a-bout way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can launch it. You will need a host though to hold your files. You will also want a domain name. You can host your site on Github using your personal page for free. The url would be something like `ExampleName.github.io` If you have your website local on your computer, just double click your index.html and you can view what it will be like when launched.

Here is a simple way to host your website: https://pages.github.com